# Google analytics not counting pages loaded with AJAX, but they apear in real time information

Tags: ajax, google-analytics

I recently started using AJAX for loading content into the front page. I searched this problem and I found that i had to add a little piece of code.

```
    ga('set', 'page', pagePath);//pagePath = consulted URL
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Now, the problem is that, even though i can see in the real time informacion when another page's content is loaded into the front page, those visits are not being loged.

This is the analytics code I'm using

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: @EikePierstorff like 5/10 minutes, but at the same time, I tested if accessing those pages directly would be counted as a visit, and they were.

Comment: @EikePierstorff but normal visits are being reported, are ajax loaded pages any different? thank you

Comment: Sorry, that was me being stupid and not reading your question properly. No, ajax visits are not any different as far as Google Analytics is concerned.

Comment: Are you perhaps not waiting long enough for the data to be processed? So you would see the page hit in RT, but you need to wait up to 24 hours for the date to appear in your reports.

Comment: @Eike Pierstorff I think i've found the problem. There are no changes on the page title dimension, but there are in the page dimension. Maybe it is because the page title is not being updated every time the elements load?

Comment: The title's will be only updated if you put the set and the pageview call in the success event callback of the ajax call.  It's hard to see from your code if you are doing that.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I wasn't doing that, I added it and know it reports, thank you, i will update as soon as I get back from college. The problem was that google analytics was reporting, but not by page title